# Term for number only divisible by 1, itself, and its square root

Tags: prime-numbers

Do numbers only divisible by 1, themselves, and their square roots have a specific term?

Seems like they're all squares of primes: 1, 9, 25, 49, 121, 169...
I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, I apologize if that's the case. Searching using the obvious keywords didn't bring anything directly referencing this class of numbers to light.

Comment: $1$ is not a square of a prime. Obviously these numbers must be square themselves, can you prove that a square of a composite number does not have the property you seek?

Comment: OEIS is always a good place to look https://oeis.org/A001248 ... $p_n^2$ ?

Comment: there are collective terms such as "prime powers"  and "prime squares."

Comment: @player3236 I don't care about proving anything, just looking for a name for the class of numbers that strictly complies with the rules I stated

Comment: @WillJagy If an example of a prime power is 64 (2^6), that class of numbers does not conform to the rules I mentioned

Comment: I meant "prime squares" for you. I use the phrase; there may or may not be anyone else who uses it. For me, it is a useful phrase relating to binary quadratic forms with integer coefficients

Comment: @WillJagy I agree it's useful, it was the first thing I thought of. But since I didn't find anything which specifically defined it like this I wasn't sure if there was another term in use that I was missing.

Comment: I wouldn't think so. The standard problem, given $f(x,y) = ax^2 + bxy + c y^2,$  is to describe the prime values of $f.$  A related problem, given some $x^2 + n y^2,$ is to describe the squares with $\gcd(x,y) = 1,$  especially the prime squares. The best known book with background is Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$ I have the first edition, there is a second, it corrects at least one typo in a formula that I use.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks for the link. The descriptions there are exactly what I'm thinking of. Perhaps other than "squares of primes" or "prime squares", there is no other name.

Comment: @WillJagy I appreciate your comments, they have helped me resolve this question.

Answer (score 0):

They are the numbers such that $k = p^2$, where $p$ is a prime, and also $1$.